# app is rejected because of imageWithName(Binary Rejected)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

My app is **rejected** because of the issue given below. i didnt find "`imageWithName`" in my code.kindly suggest me what should i do now??
i am searching this from last 2 days but i am not getting where the prblem is...
For info i would like to tell you that i am using `google carboard plugin` in this only.No ads at all.

Looking foward to your suggestions...

==============================
Performance - 2.5.1

Your app still uses or references the following non-public APIs:

`imageWithName`:

The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

Next Steps

Please revise your app to remove any non-public APIs. If you have defined methods in your source code with the same names as the above-mentioned APIs, we suggest altering your method names so that they no longer collide with Apple's private APIs to avoid your application being flagged in future submissions.

Additionally, if you are using third party libraries, please update to the most recent version of those libraries. If you do not have access to the libraries' source, you may be able to search the compiled binary using the "strings" or "otool" command line tools. The "strings" tool can output a list of the methods that the library calls and "otool -ov" will output the Objective-C class structures and their defined methods. These tools can help you narrow down where the problematic code resides. You could also use the "nm" tool to verify if any third-party libraries are calling these APIs.

Resources

For information on the "nm" tool, please see the ["nm tool" Xcode manual page.](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html)

If there are no alternatives for providing the functionality your app requires, you may wish to file an [enhancement request](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

If you have difficulty reproducing a reported issue, please try testing the workflow described in [Technical Q&A QA1764: How to reproduce bugs reported against App Store submissions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/_index.html).

If you have code-level questions after utilizing the above resources, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. When the DTS engineer follows up with you, please be ready to provide:
- complete details of your rejection issue(s)
- screenshots
- steps to reproduce the issue(s)
- symbolicated crash logs - if your issue results in a crash log

please help me!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to use nm or otool to find out any private api method call?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @Paulw11 Xcode-7.3.1

Comment: @NightFury  No. how to find out plz tell me

Comment: See https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/296